# Approximating $e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}$ to a gamma density function.

Tags: statistics, power-series, exponential-function, approximation, gamma-distribution

Is there an analytical approximation that results in the following:

$\dfrac{x^{\theta-1}.(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})}{\Gamma({\theta}).(a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta})}\simeq \dfrac{x^{\theta^*-1}.e^{-cx}}{\Gamma({\theta^*}).c^{-\theta^*}}\ \ \ \ \forall x\in[0,\infty)\ \ ,\ \  b\geq a\ \ ,\ \ a,b,c,\theta,\theta^*>0$

Where the right hand side is the density of a gamma random variable with a shape $\theta^*$ and rate $c$.

I have already found some numerical examples for the approximation. For instance:

$\dfrac{x^{1-1}.(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})}{\Gamma({1}).(1^{-1}-2^{-1})}=2(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})\simeq \dfrac{x^{1.882-1}.e^{-1.256x}}{\Gamma(1.882).1.256^{-1.882}}$

Also, for the extreme cases an analytical approximation is easy to derive:

$\lim_{b\to a}\dfrac{x^{\theta-1}.(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})}{\Gamma({\theta}).(a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta})}= \dfrac{x^{(\theta+1)-1}.e^{-ax}}{\Gamma({\theta+1}).a^{-(\theta+1)}}$

$\lim_{b\to \infty}\dfrac{x^{\theta-1}.(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})}{\Gamma({\theta}).(a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta})}= \dfrac{x^{\theta-1}.e^{-ax}}{\Gamma({\theta}).a^{-\theta}}$

However, is there a general approximation that works for any arbitrary value of $b$?

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to calculate a notion of distance between the true and the approximated distribution, which can then be optimized for the parameters in question. The simplest way to set this up would be to minimize the squared vertical distance between the two distributions

$$D(c,\theta^*)=\int_0^\infty(F(x;a,b,\theta)-F_\text{approx}(x;c,\theta^*))^2dx$$

It is clear from the form of the distributions and from the restrictions placed on the parameters, that the integrals converge for any choice of $a,b,c,\theta,\theta^*>0$. Also, it is easy to show that $D(c,\theta^*)$ is continuous and twice differentiable for all values of the parameters.

Defining the quantity

$$f(x;a,z):=\frac{a^z}{\Gamma(z)}x^{z-1}e^{-ax}$$

we can write the derivatives of $D$ with respect to $(c,\theta^*)$ as

$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial c}=-c\int_0^\infty f(x;c,\theta^*)\left(f(x;c,\theta^*)-\frac{a^{-\theta}}{a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}}f(x;a,\theta)+\frac{b^{-\theta}}{a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}}f(x;b,\theta)\right)dx$$

$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial \theta^*}=-\frac{\ln c-\psi(\theta^*)}{c}\frac{\partial D}{\partial c}+\\+\int_0^\infty\ln x~ f(x;c,\theta^*)\left(f(x;c,\theta^*)-\frac{a^{-\theta}}{a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}}f(x;a,\theta)+\frac{b^{-\theta}}{a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}}f(x;b,\theta)\right)dx$$

and by using the expressions for the integrals

$$\int_0^\infty f(x;a,w)f(x;b,z)dx=\frac{\Gamma(z+w-1)}{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)a^{-w}b^{-z}(a+b)^{w+z-1}}$$

$$\int_0^\infty\ln x ~ f(x;a,w)f(x;b,z)dx=\frac{\Gamma(z+w-1)}{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)a^{-w}b^{-z}(a+b)^{w+z-1}}\left(\psi(w+z-1)-\frac{w+z-1}{a+b}\right)$$

which results in the system of equations

$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial c}=-c\left[\frac{c\Gamma(2\theta^*-1)}{2^{2\theta^*-1}\Gamma^2(\theta^*)}+\frac{c^{\theta^*}\Gamma(\theta+\theta^*-1)}{(a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta})\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(\theta^*)}\left(\frac{1}{(a+c)^{\theta+\theta^*-1}}-\frac{1}{(b+c)^{\theta+\theta^*-1}}\right)\right]=0$$

$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial \theta^*}+\frac{\ln c-\psi(\theta^*)}{c}\frac{\partial D}{\partial c}=\\\left[\frac{c\Gamma(2\theta^*-1)}{2^{2\theta^*-1}\Gamma^2(\theta^*)}(\psi(2\theta^*-1)-\frac{2\theta^*-1}{2c})+\frac{c^{\theta^*}\Gamma(\theta+\theta^*-1)}{\left(a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}\right)\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(\theta^*)}\left(\frac{\psi(\theta+\theta^*-1)-\frac{\theta+\theta^*-1}{a+c}}{(a+c)^{\theta+\theta^*-1}}-\frac{\psi(\theta+\theta^*-1)-\frac{\theta+\theta^*-1}{b+c}}{(b+c)^{\theta+\theta^*-1}}\right)\right]=0$$

Using the first equation, the second one may be written in the slightly more concise form

$$\frac{c\Gamma(2\theta^*-1)}{2^{2\theta^*-1}\Gamma^2(\theta^*)}\left(\psi(2\theta^*-1)-\psi(\theta+\theta^*-1)-\frac{2\theta^*-1}{2c}\right)+\frac{c^{\theta^*}\Gamma(\theta+\theta^*)}{\left(a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}\right)\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(\theta^*)}\left(\frac{1}{(a+c)^{\theta+\theta^*}}-\frac{1}{(b+c)^{\theta+\theta^*}}\right)=0$$

Generally, this system would have to be solved numerically. One possible reduction of this problem that may yield a decent approximate solution is given by setting $\theta^*=\theta+1$, which matches the behavior of the two functions at the origin for $b\geq a$. We should expect that the optimal value for $\theta^*$ should satisfy this equation to some degree of accuracy. This reduction can be solved by solving the equation

$$c^{\theta}\left(\frac{1}{(b+c)^{2\theta}}-\frac{1}{(a+c)^{2\theta}}\right)=-\frac{a^{-\theta}-b^{-\theta}}{2^{2\theta}}$$

This always has a solution for the given parameter range, and this fact can be shown analytically.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. So my understanding is that taking the loss function to be the squared difference between the pdf's would give infinitely many combinations of $c$ and $\theta^*$ as the answer. I previously tried to use the KL-divergence as the loss function and used grids of  $c$ and $\theta^*$ to find the minimal loss function. I think with KL divergence the answers could not be made analytically. Anyway, my point was to see if there were an analytically unique answer for the question, which according to your loss function I think there is not.

Comment: There are two equations for two unknowns, so I expect there to only be a few solutions, definitely not infinite. The system doesn't look degenerate, and the functions involved in the minimization don't seem to be oscillatory. Can you point out why the system has infinite solutions?  I agree about the lack of analytical answer though; the functional form is too complicated.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @DinosaurEgg . I am trying to construct an MLE algorithm for a paper. The left-hand side is the posterior distribution. If I can find a gamma distribution that approximates the posterior, I can claim that Gamma is a pseudo-conjugate distribution and I will be done. Your solution is sound, but eventually having to iterate the computations as you wrote many times is costly. Ideally I need a final solution for the right-hand side that can be plugged in the formula, computation-free.  If interested, I can send you my manuscript. I am also not averse to making you coauther.

Comment: Thank you for your offer. I'm not sure I can construct anything analytic off the top of my head right now but an idea would be to construct lookup tables with the optimal solutions for various $(a,b,\theta)$ and these can be used as a database from the code if the solutions are smooth enough, then Newton's method could finish off the optimization of the solution starting with a seed from a nearby problem. Another issue is to of course prove that that representation is faithful enough and bound the error which I also don't know how to do.